# My code runs my local machine but on heroku: error [TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]] {code: 'ERR_INVALID_CHAR'}

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api

I have a chatbot using the openAI API to ask specific prompts about a certain topic. When I run the code on my local machine there is no issues. However, when I deployed it to heroku I get the following error:

> error [TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]].

I have tried to add an authorization header in the fetch() POST request but it doesn't solve it. Any clue of where the error might be coming from?

```
try {
      fetchEventSource('/api/chat', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${encodedApiKey}`,
        },

        body: JSON.stringify({
          question,
          history,
        }),
        signal: ctrl.signal,
        onmessage: (event) => {
          if (event.data === '[DONE]') {
            setMessageState((state) => ({
              history: [...state.history, [question, state.pending ?? '']],
              messages: [
                ...state.messages,
                {
                  type: 'apiMessage',
                  message: state.pending ?? '',
                  sourceDocs: state.pendingSourceDocs,
                },
              ],
              pending: undefined,
              pendingSourceDocs: undefined,
            }));
            setLoading(false);
            ctrl.abort();
          } else {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data.sourceDocs) {
              setMessageState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                pendingSourceDocs: data.sourceDocs,
              }));
            } else {
              setMessageState((state) => ({
                ...state,
                pending: (state.pending ?? '') + data.data,
              }));
            }
          }
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError('An error occurred while fetching the data. Please try again.');
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
```

This is my fetch request. It might be coming from somewhere else but I believe that it might be some issue with the headers. I have also added the configuration variables on heroku and I can't solve it.

Comment: Whatever is in `encodedApiKey` is not valid or HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

No issue with your syntax, if it works locally I would say the issue can only come from the config variables, since you're not defining encodedApiKey here. I'd make sure the relation is setup well - no experience with heroku so without more info it would be hard to tell. Making sure you code can access your configuration variables without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value of **encodedApiKey** is not correct. You can print it to be sure it's correctly defined. It should of the form `sk-somethingVeryLong`

In Heroku, you can set up your environment variables either using their CLI.

`heroku config:set OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-something`

Or via your project settings
[image: heroku dashboard for env vairabels]

In your code, you can then access the value of this environment variable with `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY`.